# Google map controls freeze in Webkit when 3d transform is used

Tags: javascript, google-maps, webkit, freeze, css-transforms

This won't come up too often, but it's really puzzling, and if anyone could suggest a remedy, I'd appreciate it.

I have 2 Google maps on a page showing different locations.  They are initiated separately using nearly identical code (geocoding and map_canvas id's are of course different).  When I put these next to each other on the page, there's no problem. Everything works.

But I'd like to use a CSS3 3D transformation for a "card flip" effect. Opening the page shows 1 map (within a div). Clicking a button on the page initiates the transformation and the div flips over, revealing the second map. When I do this, the controls on the second map--the zoom, street view, panning, etc.--don't work. When you hover over this second map, the cursor does not change to a hand or pointer. Everything's frozen. On the first map, though, these controls remain operational, both when the page is first opened and after flipping back to it.

This problem occurs in Safari, Chrome, and Opera. In addition, in Safari the zoom buttons and street-view guy disappear a second after the map is initialized. But in Firefox, all controls on both maps work fine.

I tried delaying the initialization of the 2nd map till after the flip had occurred. This made no difference.

I've also added the often-recommended fix for frozen map controls:

```
#backmap_canvas img,
.gmnoprint img,
.gm-style img  {
    max-width: none; /* I've also tried "inherit" here */
    max-height: none;
}
```

Again, this seemingly has no effect.

Since this works in Firefox and because I get no javascript error messages, I have to think my code for the maps and the flipping is okay. It's long, but I'll include it here in case I'm missing something.

If anyone has any thoughts about this, please let me know.

Thanks.
Mark

HTML:

```
<section class="main clearfix" > <!-- rotating panel container for 3D -->
   <div id="flippanel"> <!-- this flips -->
      <article class="clearfix face"> <!-- front face of card -->
         <!-- there's text and an image in here-->
         <div id="map_canvas">
         </div>
      </article>
      <article class="clearfix face">  <!-- back face -->
         <!-- more text, etc. -->
         <div id="backmap_canvas">
         </div>
      </article>
   </div> <!-- flippanel -->
</section> <!-- main -->
```

CSS: (no prefixes except -webkit- to save space)

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;   /* stop ghosting on transforms */
    margin-left: -1%;   /* fixes left edge problem in Opera*/
    min-height: 34em;
    width: 90%;
    font-size-adjust: .44;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}
#flippanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.7s, background-color .2s .4s linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% center;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* here & below stops flicker */
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#flippanel.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
#flippanel #map_canvas {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s .4s linear;
}
#flippanel.flipped #map_canvas {
    opacity: 0;
}
#flippanel article {
    position: absolute; /* each article holds different face */
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
article:last-child {  /* back of flipped card: 2nd map */
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );   /* stops mirror effect */
}
#backmap_canvas,
#map_canvas {
    position: relative;
    top: -3.5em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 324px;
    max-width: none;
    width: 332px;
}
#backmap_canvas img,    /* fixes for frozen map controls ??? */
#location .gmnoprint img,
#location .gm-style img {
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
}
#location .gm-style label {
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
}
```

Javascript: (1st is called onload, 2nd when transformation is done)

```
initializeMap: function() {
   var latlngH = new google.maps.LatLng(39.758746,-105.027254);
   var centerH = new google.maps.LatLng(39.750378,-105.01606);
   var optionsH = {
   center: centerH,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var mapH = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), optionsH);
   var markerH = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: mapH,
      icon: "images/redpin-slant.png",
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latlngH,
      cursor: "hand"
   });
}

initializeBackmap: function() {
   var latlngS = new google.maps.LatLng(39.759039,-104.900743);
   var centerS = new google.maps.LatLng(39.764317,-104.907009);
   var optionsS = {
      center: centerS,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var mapS = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("backmap_canvas"), optionsS);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:mapS,
      icon:"images/redpin-slant.png",
      position: latlngS,
      cursor: "hand"
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time seeing what you're trying to do. Without seeing your code for the flip, I can't comment on it, but I wonder if your issue with Safari sheds some light here. I turned off the `overflow: hidden` on `.main` and `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on `#flippanel article` and found the controls to work fine: 
https://jsfiddle.net/u70sm4an/

The overflow was hiding the map controls. It could be that the different handling of transforms from webkit to moz might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Benjamin. Flip is activated with javascript which adds/removes classname "flipped" to the <div id='flippanel'>. Probably I should have actually posted the page, so you could see it in action. I've done so now: [link](http://www.idesignmagic.com/testing/classroom-locations.php).  While I suspect that the cotrols work on jsfiddle because you have both maps on the same level (i.e., there's no flip occurring), your suggestion about backface-visibility is something I'll definitely explore. Any other suggesions you have will be welcome.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong. First, `overflow-hidden` doesn't play nicely with 3d transforms. You've got a lot of absolutely positioned elements, and no z-indexing, so it looks like the flipped `article` is ending up behind something.

I messed around with it and found a solution. Here are my changes: https://www.diffchecker.com/slirwk5q

You'll need to give `.main` a non-relative height for the black background.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin for your work. I tried your solution. To preserve the differences, I created a new css file, called don-edited.css, and a new page to test it: [link](http://www.idesignmagic.com/testing/locations-edited.php)  Removing some of the css clearly had an impact on the page, but that can be fixed later. Problem is, the main issue has not been solved: the controls still don't work on the flipped map in Chrome, Safari, & Opera. Still works in Firefox. I added z-index:100 to #backmap_canvas and overflow:visible to #location .main.  No effect.

Comment: The z-index needs to be on the front-facing panel, not the back panel. Put it on the first `article`.

Comment: `z-index` doesn't quite work the way I think you're trying to use it. You should be using it to push forward (or back) items that are otherwise of equal importance, rather than trying to boost an individual element to the top. Additionally, z-index is a funny mistress: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

As an aside, think about the way you're assigning CSS to your elements-- you're using pseudo-elements to affect two singular blocks. You have a lot of redundancy and it's incredibly difficult to understand. Clear class names would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the z-index article, @Benjamin. It's interesting and perhaps on-point that transforms create a new stacking context. But what wasn't addressed--and what I still find puzzling--is the effective stacking order of the back of a flippable card vis-a-vis the front. If the front of a card is stacked on top and you then flip it over, is the front still at the top? Or should I change the stacking order during the flip? Anyway, sorry about the overall complexity. I'll take everything out except the 2 maps, which should make it clearer. Probably take me a few minutes.

Comment: @MarkLamprey the card with the higher z-index will remain on top, but when you "flip" it, the top will become the bottom, just like an actual card. `z-index` doesn't change that. Anyway, just adding z-index to the first `article` will fix your problem. Check it out-- if you try to drag the bottom of the map, you'll see it works, but the top doesn't. Inspect the map controls, and you'll see that you've actually inspected a `p` from the other card. An appropriate `z-index` context on the first `article` solves this.

Comment: They're telling us to chat instead of use these comments.  Fine with me. I don't know what will happen if we ignore that. I've simplified the code significantly. The articles are now classed as .front and .back. The new css is called don-decimated.css. Here's the new [link](http://www.idesignmagic.com/testing/locations-decimated.php)  i'm making progress, but there are oddities: now the first map's controls are frozen. When I flip it, the controls unfreeze but the 2nd map is reversed. Flipping it back, it shows the 2nd map correctly with the controls functioning. But I've lost the first map.

Comment: You should revert to the prior version. You've obviously lost something in the mix. If you go back and make the `z-index` change I described above, you'll have it functioning the way you wanted. Once there, you can start to pull out styles into separate classes and make sure that you don't lose anything important.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it worked!  Thanks.  Obviously there's still a lot I don't understand, but I can use brute force and trial-and-error from here.  Many many thanks for all your effort. I'm sure I wouldn't have been able to solve it myself.

Comment: psst, if the answer was correct, can you mark it? Thanks.

Comment: Done (I think. Anyway, I upvoted your key answers.) Thanks, @Benjamin